# Why does Perl create an empty array reference via grep?

Tags: perl

I may be missing something obvious, but I'm at a loss as to why the following Perl creates an array reference via [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), but not [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) or another general reference?

```pl
print @$arr; # no output
print ref $arr; # no output
print scalar @$arr; # no output
print ref $arr; # no output
print sort @$arr; # no output
print ref $arr; # no output
print grep { 0 } @$arr; # no output
print ref $arr; # ARRAY
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, or maybe it's just one of those things, but it stumped me and I wondered if anyone knew the answer...

I've tested this on Perl 5.8 and 5.10 and get the same behaviour on both.

Comment: I think that what you have there is a bug in Perl.

Comment: ...but I thought it was never a bug in Perl!

Comment: Note that `scalar` results in absolutely no code. It simply changes the context flag on its operand. This is one of the most unusual of the functions, so not a good example of anything!

Comment: Oh, Perl has [plenty of bugs](https://rt.perl.org/Public/) :-)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I originally thought it was de-referencing a `undef` value causing the array to be created but was surprised not to have seen this before...

Comment: You thought correctly. It only happens in lvalue context, though. `$x = @$arr;` won't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interesting question is why don't any of the others. Dereferencing in lvalue context will autovivify the operand if it's undef.

```
$ perl -E'@$arr = "b"; say $arr // "[undef]"'
ARRAY(0x335b558)
```

Arguments are always passed by reference to subs, so they are evaluated in lvalue context.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { }  f( @$arr ); say $arr // "[undef]"'
ARRAY(0x284e9f8)
```

But the "functions" in perlfunc are actually operators, and as such, they get to invent their own syntax and calling conventions. Perl knows that `sort` won't modify its operands when using the default compare function, so it doesn't evaluate them in lvalue context.

```
$ perl -E'sort @$arr; say $arr // "[undef]"'
[undef]
```

`grep` aliases `$_` to each item passed to it, so it its arguments can be modified (even though that's usually not a good idea), so its arguments are evaluated in lvalue context.

```
$ perl -E'@a = "a"; grep { $_ = uc($_) } @a; say @a'
A
```

Comment: The same goes for `for` and `map`, so clearly you are on to something. The code block itself seems irrelevant, the fact that `$_` is aliased seems to be enough.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of `for`/`map`, knew I was missing some extra tests. This caught us out in a check during a new feature build and was definitely confusing!